# Erro de SSL/TLS ao tentar realizar transação API Cielo

Tags: c#

Durante toda a semana tive problemas nas chamadas para a API deles, recebo somente o seguinte erro:

> A conexão subjacente estava fechada erro inesperado em um envio

Meu código chamado no RestSharp é:

```
public Transaction Transaction_CreditCard(Transaction transaction)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "text/json");
    request.AddHeader("merchantkey", this.merchantKey);
    request.AddHeader("merchantid", this.merchantID);
    request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transaction), ParameterType.RequestBody);
    return Execute<Transaction>(request, this.apiUrl);
}

private T Execute<T>(RestRequest request, string url) where T : new()
{    
    var cliente = new RestClient(url);        
    var response = cliente.Execute<T>(request);

    if (response.ErrorException != null)
    {
        string message = "Erro durante a requisição " + request.Resource;
        var cieloException = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);       
        throw cieloException;
    }
        return response.Data;
    }
```

Porém meu `response.ContentLength` é igual a `0`. Eu já configurei o SSL no meu site, já adicionar o `user-agent` e não resolveu também

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Vc implementou o pagamento pela Cielo ? pode me mandar um exemplo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa consegui resolver a mensagem de erro inserindo a seguinte linha na função `Execute`:

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

[`SecurityProtocol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) é o protocolo de segurança que o service point irá utilizar nas requisições Web ou seja, setando `Tls12` estou automaticamente atualizando as minhas requisições para o TLS 2.0 que é o protocolo mais seguro, assim a requisição ocorreu perfeitamente.