# Chamada a API com HttpClient - POST

Tags: c#, api

É a primeira vez que desenvolvo algo do tipo, então não sei muito o que pode estar errado.

Estou fazendo uma chamada a uma API com o `HttpClient`, dessa forma:

```
private string autenticar()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string baseUrl = "/geosite-telecom-api/auth/token";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("Mozilla", "5.0"));

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "username", Usuario }, { "password", Senha } };
            var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

            var retornos = client.PostAsync(Url + baseUrl + $"?username={Usuario}&password={Senha}", encodedContent).Result;

            return "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Esse código acima está recebendo o erro:

> A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um envio.

Coloquei o retorno com `string` vazio para que eu possa testar somente a conexão com a API por hora.

Testei a URL no SoapUi e consegui fazer direitinho.

Comment: Suspeito de alguma coisa relacionada a conexão HTTPS. Dificil ter certeza sem conhecer os detalhes da API que está sendo chamada...
Pode compartilhar a documentação? Uma sugestão que pode ajudar: utilize o [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) para capturar as requisições, tanto a feita com sucesso no SoapUI quanto esta via código.
Assim você poderá comparar uma chamada contra a outra e ir corrigindo.

Comment: @Minelli não sei se posso ainda liberar a documentação pois parece que eles liberam somente mediante pagamento do serviço, mas vou confirmar e se puder coloco aqui. De toda forma vou testar o Fiddler e ver como fica. Já te dou um retorno ai. Obrigada.

Comment: @Minelli muito obrigada cara, realmente o problema era no HTTPS, somente modifiquei o `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` e funcionou! Obrigada. Se quiser colocar como resposta, eu marco como respondido. Valeu!

Comment: Um outro detalheziho... você está fazendo um Post, mas passando os parâmetros por Query String... não seria o caso de mudar para GET? ou remover esses parâmetros, deixando apenas o `encondedContent`?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo já mudei isso também, junto com o ServicePointManager. Obrigada.

Comment: é recomendável definir o protocolo de segurança uma vez que o sistema é iniciado, por exemplo em uma classe StartUp ou Program, não há necessidade de alterar o protocolo sempre que uma chamada http for realizada. Atc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pesquisei algumas coisas sobre o assunto, após os comentários do Minelli na pergunta, indicando que o problema era no HTTPS.

Basicamente o problema consiste em modificar o protocolo de segurança para conseguir acessar a API. Modifiquei o código para:

```
private string autenticar()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("Mozilla", "5.0"));

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "username", Usuario }, { "password", Senha } };
            var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var retornos = client.PostAsync(Url + baseUrl, encodedContent).Result;

            var resultJson = retornos.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var retornoToken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(resultJson);

            return retornoToken.token;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Onde Url e baseUrl já são definidas previamente na classe e consistem em:

```
Url = "https:\\site.com.br";
baseUrl = "\metodo\funcao";
```

O foco da solução está na linha:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Nela eu defino explicitamente qual protocolo de segurança deve ser utilizado para acesso a API e não utilizo o protocolo default do Framework.

Pesquisando mais a fundo, descobri que o protocolo default do .NET Framework 4.6 para cima é o `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` e eu estou utilizando o .NET Framework 4.5.

**Fontes de pesquisa**

[Stack Overflow (inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382254/update-net-web-service-to-use-tls-1-2)
[Stack Overflow (português)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/323041/erro-de-ssl-tls-ao-tentar-realizar-transa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-api-cielo)
[Stack Overflow (inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920429/is-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-enabled-by-default-for-net-4-5-and-net-4-5-1)

Obrigada ao Minelli, sem ele eu nunca teria me preocupado com o protocolo de segurança.